# Count number of circles in image using c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

i want to write a c# program to count number of colered circles like the below image.

if any one have any algorithm or code to show how i can do this please share it with me.

here is sample image:(its not clearly sharp but most of images is sharp enough)

[image]
<sub>(source: [biologyofhumanaging.com](http://www.biologyofhumanaging.com/slides/bld220c1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Do you want us to make it for you? :P

Comment: This question doesn't show any initial research effort. What have you tried? Have you searched for potential approaches? If so, please let us know what they are and what isn't working. Thank you.

Comment: Actualy may some one have exp. with some like this. or have any idea to how to do. also we need to count purple circles.

Comment: @Rami: Looks like it might be a hardware bug, as those two circles are actually purple. :)

Answer (score 4):

From the sample image, the background and circles seem to be easily distinguishable.  I would try segmenting the image by thresholding the image (e.g. Make the circles black and the background White)

Once you've done this you should be able to get a fairly good estimate by dividing the number of black pixels by the average number of pixels in a circle.

I am assuming all the images are the same style (and size) and that you don't need an exact count.